# error en creacion de trigger en phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Se esta creando un trigger en la tabla productos para que cuando se inserte una fila de productos nuevos con sus respectivos campos (codigoarticulo, nombrearticulo, precio, insertado) genere un trigger e inserte estos nuevos campos en la tabla reg_productos

```
CREATE TRIGGER PRODUCTOS_A_I AFTER
INSERT
    ON
    productos FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT
    INTO
    reg_productos (codigoarticulo,
    nombrearticulo,
    precio,
    insertado)
VALUES (new.codigoarticulo,
new.nombrearticulo,
new.precio,
NOW())
```

El error que phpymyadmin lanza es:

> #1054 - La columna 'codigoarticulo' en NEW es desconocida

Comment: ¿Y si cambias NEW por OLD?

Comment: de que tipo es codigoarticulo? seguro que es un autoincrementable no?

Comment: Muestra la estructura de las tablas implicadas, parece que la columna que usas para `NEW` no se llama así. Por otra parte, tres `new` en este TRIGGER revelan un grave problema de **redundancia de datos** en tu modelo. ¿Hay algo que justifique eso?

Comment: creo que no tiene mucho sentido que ponga old en vez de new porque lo que quiero es que inserte en la tabla PRODUCTOS_A_I el codigoarticulo, nombrearticulo, precio, insertado de un producto nuevo

Comment: codigoarticulo no es autoincrementable